# How to use PostLogoutRedirectUris in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, identityserver3

I want to use PostLogoutRedirectUris from identity server to redirect based on the domain it is requesting. My client page is like this:-

```
 new Client
   {
     Enabled = true,
     ClientName = "ClientA",
     ClientId = "ClientId",
    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
     "http://localhost:3001/callback"
    },
   RequireSignOutPrompt =false,
   AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
   {
    "http://localhost:3001/"
   },
  PostLogoutRedirectUris=new List<string>
  {
  "http://localhost:3001/logout",
  "http://localhost:3002/logout"
  },
   AllowedScopes = new List<string>
   {
     "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
  },
 },
```

Now how to handle the multiple string within the PostLogoutRedirectUris based on the request in reactsjs? What need to pass from rectajs UI?Please assist me.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are asking. However, to log out you need to call the endsession endpoint, passing the id token and post logout redirect url as arguments.

```
/connect/endsession?id_token_hint={id token}&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001/logout
```

where {id token} is the id token returned from identity server when calling the `/connect/authorize endpoint.` You should be able to set the `post_logout_redirect_uri` according to the domain you are on.

See the docs here https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/endSession.html

Note that you MUST send an id token back for the redirect to work. And I assume you have set `EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect` to true in `AuthenticationOptions`?

Comment: is there a way to pass querystring in PostLogoutRedirectUris so how the client side matching can be done, as querystrings value can change let   `PostLogoutRedirectUris=new List<string>
  {
  "http://localhost:3001/login?search="
  }`